# Remove children of dynamic list of lists

Tags: c#, list

I have a dynamic list where it could be infinite child list.
Each list have an ID and then it have a ParentID.

I got the ID of one of the list and i want to delete all the list down the hierarchy by taking all the list that have that ID as ParentID. Then i want to take all those lists and do the same thing until all child lists of the first item is removed.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Yeah it's called recursion. Show your code and what you have tried.

Comment: The thing is that i have started a couple of times by trying different approaches but then relized it won't work that way.... Do i have to have a foreach loop where i call the same method where the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a recursive algorithm. In words, it can be described as following:

1. remove item with `ID` = x
2. find all children with `ParentID` = x
3. repeat from step 1 for every children's ID

Assuming that you have the following class definition:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
}
```

It can be done with the following method:

```
void RemoveRecursively(List<Item> list, int id)
{
    list.RemoveAll(x => x.ID == id);

    foreach (var removingId in list.Where(x => x.ParentID == id).Select(x => x.ID).ToArray()) 
        RemoveRecursively(list, removingId);
}
```

Some information on what recursion is:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/recursion
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/z3dk2cc3(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Would you not get errors about removing from list while iterating over it..?

Comment: @CallumLinington I have updated it. Now, it takes an array of IDs, and then iterates :)

Comment: I tend just to reverse them, I think that means you won't I can't say I'm 100% sure

Comment: No I just tried it, you can modify lists, just arrays. But I do reverse arrays.

Comment: @CallumLinington I guess, it works if you remove item at index `i`. However, `RemoveRecursively` may remove random items. If performance is not very important or tree isn't very big, then I would prefer this method - it is more "transparent" and clear.